# Odd behaviour when writing to a .txt file that is over 1GB

Tags: c++, file, text, storage, large-data

I have some code that is finding prime numbers, it outputs the numbers into a .txt file, and this seems to work fine, up until it reaches 1GB (i'm not sure of the exact file size but it is around that). After it reaches 1GB the file size seems to scale rapidly, and I believe this is because whole chunks of the numbers are being repeated. Here is my code:

```js
#include "pch.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>

int nextInt = 1;
std::ofstream file;

bool TestPrime(int number)
{
 double rootInt = sqrt(number);
 for (int i = 3; i <= rootInt; i += 2)
 {
  double divValue = (double)number / i;
  if (int(divValue) == divValue)
  {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}
int GetNextNumber()
{
 static std::mutex m;
 const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
 return (nextInt += 2);
}

void PrimeFinderThread()
{
 while (true)
 {
  int number = GetNextNumber();
  bool isPrime = TestPrime(number);
  if (isPrime)
  {
   std::string fileOutput = std::to_string(number) + "-";
   file << fileOutput;
  }
 }
}

int main() {
 file.open("primes.txt", std::ofstream::app);
 file << "2-";
 std::thread threads[4];
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  threads[i] = std::thread(PrimeFinderThread);
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  threads[i].join();
 }
 return 0;
}
```

And here is an extract from the start of the .txt file:

```js
2-3-5-7-11-13-17-19-23-29-31-37-41-43-47-53-59-61-67-71-73-79-83-89-97-101-103-107-109-113-127-131-137-139-149-151-157-163-167-173-179-181-191-193-197-199-211-223-227-229-233-239-241-251-257-263-269-271-277-281-283-293-307-311-313-317-331-337-347-349-353-359-367-373-379-383-389-397-401-409-419-421-431-433-439-443-449-457-461-463-467-479-487-491-499-503-509-521-523-541-547-557-563-569-571-577-587-593-599-601-607-613-617-619-631-641-643-647-653-659-661-673-677-683-691-701
```

And here is an extract from somewhere in the middle of the file:

```js
2038621267--2038621265--2038621269--2038621263--2038621259--2038621257--2038621255--2038621253--2038621261--2038621249--2038621247--2038621245--2038621367--2038621251--2038621243--2038621237--2038621239--2038621233--2038621231--2038621235--2038621241--2038621227--2038621223--2038621221--2038621219--2038621217--2038621225--2038621213--2038621215--2038621209--2038621207--2038621205--2038621211--2038621203--2038621199--2038621197--2038621229--2038621193--2038621201--2038621189--2038621187--2038621185--2038621183--2038621195
```

And some from the end of the file:

```js
1812147945--1812147959--1812147941--1812147939--1812147947--1812147935--1812147933--1812147937--1812147929--1812147943--1812147925--1812147927--1812147921--1812147919--1812147917--1812147915--1812147913--1812147911--1812147923--1812147909--1812147907--1812147903--1812147901--1812147931--1812147897--1812147895--1812147893--1812147905--1812147889--1812147887--1812147885--1812147899--1812147881--1812147883--1812147891--1812147879--1812147873--1812147871--1812147875--1812147869--1812147865--1812147877--1812147867--1812147859--1812147857--1812147855--1812147853--1812147861
```

And so, there is a lot wrong with this file:

```
-There are two dashes sometimes.
-There are numbers at the end of the file that are smaller than the ones in the middle, which should 
 not happen. The numbers may be a bit out of order since it is running on multiple threads, but not 
 by that much.
-if we assume that ever number is 10 digits long, which would mean that they take up 11 bytes each, 
 the largest number it got to was about 2.2 billion. you can estimate the number of primes under that 
 number by using an estimate of the PI function which is π(x) ≈ (x/ln(x)), so the number of primes is 
 about 102 million, so they should take up about 1.1GB of storage. the .txt file is 3.1GB.
```

Some times tests I did where I measured the file size after a certain time:

```
10 Minutes : 760MB
20 Minutes : 3.1GB
30 Minutes : 14.6GB
```

I know that the file size isn't a good measure of speed, but the values are so wildly out that I think it's enough to show that something is wrong.

Comment: I don't see where you are checking for numeric overflow.  Is that a possibility?

Comment: oh that would make sense why the largest number it got to was about 2.2 billion.

Comment: although that is probably the issue, has anyone got any idea why is would cause the file to scale up rapidly like that?

Comment: the highest number it got to was 2147483579, so almost exactly the max size of a signed int.

Comment: I posted an answer to summarize, but essentially the double dash is because the overflow is causing negative numbers and the second dash is actually the minus sign.  it's repeating sequences because with negative numbers instead of steadily increasing it's actually jumping backwards and then incrementing back up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my original comment to the post and the OP's replies, it appears that the issue is numeric overflow.  Once the numbers overflow you're in chaos mode.  Some numbers may be overflowed while others are not yet overflowed, and others may be negative (hence the double dash, because the second dash is actually a minus sign)